# Select all apart from multiple ids

Tags: mysql

Hi there i am trying to select everything from one of my tables apart from two rows. Is there a way i can do this with a SQL statement?

If i where to select everything apart from one row of my table i would write a sql statement like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `id` != 4
```

How could i do this for multiple ids so lets say select everything apart from the rows with the id or 4 and 2?

I have tried this with no luck:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `id` != (4,2)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `id` != 4 AND `id` != 2
```

alternatively using an IN statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `id` NOT IN (4,2)
```

refer to the docs:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Not sure where you got that syntax from.